# What is a web job on azure, is it part of a web application or standalone

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

Is it a job attached to a web app, or is it a type of web app itself?  I tried following this example but couldn't find the add webjobs link it mentioned, just links to create a web app.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/

Comment: Think of it as cronjob ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a job is "attached" to a Web App. A Web App is the execution container for WebJobs. In some cases you might also have a companion website also running in the WebApp, but often, the Web App only contains WebJobs.

Once you have a Web App, you can create/manage WebJobs via the portal "WebJobs" blade in the new portal. You'll find it in the Settings blade under "Features".

Answer (score 1):

Another way to think of a Web Job is as an extra .exe/process that runs on the same VM as your web app, with the only special thing being that it is launched with the same set of environment variables as the web app and has access to the same set of directories.

Answer (score -1):

There's a [great post here](http://www.bananagunprogramming.com/?p=297#more-297) explaining WebJobs and how to create/operate one. Everything you need to know to get going.

Comment: Link does not work.